# Any jsp tag library to perform simple excel editing?

Tags: excel, jsp-tags

Is there any jsp tag library that can perform simple excel editing on web?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) seems to be the other common way of doing something similar. Here is a web page with [some example code](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/poi/createBox.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

[JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) gives you excel editing in Java. From this it shouldn't be too hard to roll your own JSP tags. This isn't exactly what you wanted, but no-one else had answered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such simple jsp tag, but you can use EasyXLS, a java based API, that can be used as [JSP excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/java-excel-library) as you can see in this link and create your own one.

It is not so difficult to use as Apache POI and here is a sample about how to achieve your goal:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/html/programmerGuide/basics/importFromXLSFiles.html

Basically you need to load the cells to your JSP control as in the previous sample and edit the Excel data.